# If $\mathbb Q \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q \cong \mathbb Q^\mathbb N$, why is $\mathbb Q \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q$ a $1$-dim $\mathbb Q$-v.s.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, abelian-groups

In Dummit & Foote, it is an exercise to show that $\mathbb Q \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q$ is a $1$-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

This is fairly easy: a $\mathbb Q$-basis for $\mathbb Q \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q$ is $\{1 \otimes 1\}$ since any simple tensor can be rewritten as $a/b \otimes c/d = 1 \otimes (a/b)(c/d)$. Therefore, any tensor can be rewritten as $1 \otimes x$. Then, the map $\mathbb Q \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ where $1 \otimes x \mapsto x$ is a $\mathbb Q$-linear isomorphism.

---

However, the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Q$ is isomorphic to the free $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z^\mathbb N$, and we know $M \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z^A \cong M^A$ for any $\mathbb Z$-module $M$. So, 
$$\mathbb Q \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q \cong \mathbb Q \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z^\mathbb N \cong \mathbb Q^\mathbb N$$
which is an infinite dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

**What is wrong here?**

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a free abelian group, it is not even projective as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Arguing a map from $\mathbb Q\otimes \mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q$ in that way can be tricky because it is not obviously well-defined. To get a map going out of the tensor product it is more efficient (usually) to use its universal property.

Comment: @TokenToucan I didn't want to type all the details for the proof here. I was just noting that that is the map which gives the isomorphism.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is a free $\Bbb Q$-module, but $\Bbb Q$ certainly isn't a free $\Bbb Z$-module. No two rationals are $\Bbb Z$-linearly independent, so if it were free it'd have rank $1$, but it's not $\cong\Bbb Z$. Indeed, it's divisible, unlike any free abelian group.

Comment: It's also not true that $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, or that $M \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z^A \cong M^A$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I would assume OP is just mixing up products and coproducts?  (iirc, both are true for coproducts)

Comment: @EricWofsey Yea sorry, I meant to write $\mathbb Z^{\oplus \mathbb N}$. And also meant to write $M \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z^{\oplus A} \cong M^{\oplus A}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb Q$ is a not a free $\mathbb Z$-module:

- $\mathbb Q \ne \frac{a}{b}\mathbb Z$. So, $\mathbb Q$ is not generated by a single element over $\mathbb Z$.
- If $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d} \in \mathbb Q$, then $bc\frac{a}{b} - ad\frac{c}{d}=0$. So, no set with more than two elements can be linearly independent.